# mysql 8 gives error on creating table ( running migrate command in django )

Tags: django, migration, mysql-8.0

Django3.2
mysql 5.7

I have a model name `hOEEHcQtEckeEGroJCMSGBYeRBDgddrPmvRbFSXFBtktNohn`  and its length is 48 characters and it has 1 not null field. On mysql5.7 it is working fine.

But when try to upgrade with mysql8+ migrations throws error Identifier name is too long.

This model generates following name in mysql8.5 `abcdefg_hOEEHcQtEckeEGroJCMSGBYeRBDgddrPmvRbFSXFBtktNohn _chk_1` it has 65 characters.

mysql8 limit [info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html)

I have a question what are the possible solutions to fix this issue on mysql8 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name at the database side with the [**`db_table`** Meta option [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table). For example with:

```
class BlackboardLearnerAssessmentDataTransmissionAudit(models.Model):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'transmission_audit'
```

You can thus first rename the table and then upgrade the database. If you can start from scratch, I would advise removing the migrations where you start using the `BlackboardLearnerAssessmentDataTransmissionAudit` model. You thus create all the other models with a single migration such that you never use this long name in the first place, but this assumes that you can start migrating from an *empty* database.

Comment: We have this table in production with few millions records so renaming a table might lock the table?

Comment: @AwaisQureshi: baed on [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53850/45764), will use a metadata lock, but will finish in a few seconds.